# SQL Script for this

Tags: sql-scripts

Sample Data:

[image: Sample data]

I want the value of `RNWD_NO` will be the USER REFERENCE OF THE OTHER.

ID.2 RNWD_NO will be USER_REF of ID.1 same to others.

Comment: Your question is what exactly? Do you get an error message for the code you already tried? If so, please add your code to the question.

Comment: what script to change the value of the column by the value of other column on a same table like that on my example?